# prove that {$↔,⊕$} is incomplete set?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-logic

How do i prove that Is {$↔,⊕$} not a complete set  ? I have no clue how to prove it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by induction that any formula using only these connectives is affine, that is, has one of the following forms:
$$
x_{i_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{i_\ell}, \\
x_{i_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{i_\ell} \oplus 1.
$$
Then show that there are functions not expressible in this form.

Comment: Suppose B  = ($x_1 ⊕ x_2 $)$↔$($y_1 ⊕ y_2$) , How do i prove that B can be written in one of the two forms you mentioned ?

Comment: I’m afraid that’s something you’ll have to figure out on your own.

Comment: If you help me in this step then probably induction step will be over .Can you give slightest hint ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not willing to do your homework. I already gave you a huge hint.

Comment: I did using induction , do you know any other method .Knowing more than one method always helps !

Answer (score 3):

The universal method to check whether a set of connectives is complete in this sense is [Post's classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness): there are 5 function classes such that a set of functions is complete iff it isn't a subset of any of these 5. One of the 5 is affine functions, as described in Yuval's answer; the rest are monotone, self-dual, 0-preserving, and 1-preserving functions.

It's pretty easy to show that all 5 classes are *closed*: any composition of functions from one of them will also belong to the same class. So if your set is a subset of a Post's class, it can't be complete. Showing the other direction is more complicated, but likely you'll learn the proof in the near future.

Comment: I seriously doubt the OP will learn this proof in the near future.